# Adding a class to all the required fields' labels

Tags: symfony-1.4

We have a project in symfony 1.4, and I want to add a class to the labels of all required fields. The controls are defined as,

```
    $this->setWidgets([
        'userId'        => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $userList)),
        'dateFrom'      => new chiliWidgetFormDateTime(),
        'dateTo'        => new chiliWidgetFormDateTime(),
        'status'        => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => [0 => 'All', 1 => 'Failed', 2 => 'Success', ])),
        'page'          => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
        'maxPerPage'    => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
    ]);

    $this->widgetSchema->setLabels([
        'userId'    => 'Administrator',
        'dateFrom'  => 'Login date From',
        'dateTo'    => 'Login date To',
        'status'    => 'Status'
    ]);

    $this->setValidators(array(
        'userId'      => new sfValidatorString(['required' => false]),
        'dateFrom'      => new sfValidatorDateWithTimezone(array('required' => true, 'trim' => true)),
        'dateTo'        => new sfValidatorDateWithTimezone(array('required' => true, 'trim' => true, 'modify' => '+1 day -1 second')),
        'status'        => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => [0, 1, 2])),
        'page'          => new sfValidatorInteger(array('required' => true)),
        'maxPerPage'    => new sfValidatorInteger(array('required' => true)),
    ));
```

The validator was added using above code and for adding the class, the only way seems to be available is using setAttribute like follows,

```
    $this->widgetSchema->setAttribute('class','required');
```

This adds the class to all the labels present in the `->setLabel()`. But, how to add this for a particular field? And is there anyway to do this globally for the labels of all required fields in all forms?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend symfony's sfForm and use it as base class in all your forms:

```
class myForm extends sfForm {
    public function __construct($defaults = array(), $options = array(), $CSRFSecret = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($defaults, $options, $CSRFSecret);
        foreach($this->getValidatorSchema()->getFields() as $name => $validator) {
            if($validator->getOption('required') && isset($this->widgetSchema[$name])) {
                $widget = $this->getWidget($name);
                $class = $widget->getAttribute('class');
                if($class) {
                    $class .= ' ';
                }
                $widget->setAttribute('class', $class . 'required');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For generated form do the same in `BaseFormDoctrine`, if using doctrine.